# Laravel Yajra datatables headers label not working

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

I'm using https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service implementation, and when trying to change the table header label in the service I get:

> 'DataTables warning: table id=dataTableBuilder - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7'

My service code is:

```
 public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns([
                'name' => 'Nome',
                'email' => 'Email',
                'patente.patente' => 'Patente',
                'unity.unity' => 'Unidade',
            ])
            ->parameters([
                'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
                'buttons' => ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'reload'],
            ]);
    }

    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'name',
            'email',
            'patente.patente',
            'unity.unity',
        ];
    }
```

Any suggestion? Tnks.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, solved, tnks anyway.

Solution:

```
public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns([
                'name' => [ 'title' => 'Nome' ],
                'email' => [ 'title' => 'Email' ],
                'patente.patente' => [ 'title' => 'Patente' ],
                'unity.unity' => [ 'title' => 'Unidade' ],
            ])
            ->parameters([
                'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
                'buttons' => ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'reload'],
            ]);
    }

    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'name',
            'email',
            'patente.patente',
            'unity.unity',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: what is the use of  `protected function getColumns` function?

Comment: mapping from database to view. (I think) It been more then a year since my self solution post. :D